# Compare two files with English and Japanese data

Tags: regex, perl, hash, string-comparison

I am asked to compare two files which contain some Japanese and English informaion. I use a slow approach, read two files and put them in two arrays, then use while loop to check whether the File_B's TERMS are WITHIN the lines of File_A.

File_A:

This is a boy.

ハンカ

She is a girl.

I am a man.

This apple is big.

That orange is small.

File_B:

is a

ハンカ

small

Output:

I am a man.

This apple is big.

The program I wrote works fine. However, the files I am processing are very huge. The running time is so slow if I use looping like this. My friend told me that I can put the files into hash and it will run far much quicker. I can see the point of using it but the files I have are random and also the terms in File_B can be in any part of File_A. Some previous posts suggest that I can use split the lines of File_A, put the line in hash and compare it with File_B (put File_B in the other hash as well). However, I do not know how to do it besides using ~// to check whether the line got the term.

```
open(A_FILE, "<", "FILE_A.txt");
my(@a_lines) = <A_FILE>; # read file into list
close(A_FILE);
open(B_FILE, "<", "FILE_B.txt");
my(@b_lines) = <B_FILE>; # read file into list
my($b_lines);
close(B_FILE);
open(my $out, ">",  "Useful.txt") or die "Can't open Useful.txt: $!";
$number = @b_lines;

foreach $a_line (@a_lines) # loop thru list
{
   $found = 0;
   my $sentence = $a_line;
   $i = 0;
   chomp($sentence);
   while (($i <= $number-1) and ($found == 0)){
       chomp($b_lines[$i]);
       if ($sentence =~ /$b_lines[$i]/){
           $found = 1;
       }
       $i++;
   }

   if ($found == 1) {
       print $out $sentence."\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the files... are very huge"?  100MB? 100GB?  Since you're loading both files into memory they can't be all *that* large.

Comment: File_A is around 1GB I will say. File_B is smaller, maybe around 50MB.

Comment: Every time it takes around a whole day to run the program.

Comment: Slurp File_B into one scalar variable (i.e. into a string, not an array). Don't read all File_A into memory at once. Instead read it one record at a time and check if that record matches anywhere in the string built from File_B. That will use a lot less memory and I think it would therefore run faster.

Comment: thx d5e5, but when File_B becomes a long string, how can File_A's lines compare with it? I cannot use regex to compare parts of two strings, right?
e.g. I cannot compare: "He is a boy." and "a car a boy a girl" If I want to compare them, I may need to split the string again.

Comment: Actually, the following post is quite close to the solution I want:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564378/how-can-i-take-queries-from-one-file-search-another-and-output-to-a-third-in-p

Comment: The difference is the that:
azure
Byzantine
cystitis
dyspeptic

and 

azalea        n.  flowering shrub of the rhododendron family
azure         adj. bright blue, as of the sky 
byte          n. fixed number of binary digits, often representing a single character
Byzantine     adj. of Byzantium or the E Roman Empire
cystitis      n. inflammation of the bladder
Czech         adj. of the Czech Republic or Bohemia
dyslexic      adj. suffering from dyslexia

This case can put the file into a hash easily and make the comparison, but my case is that the value may appear in anywhere of the line.

Comment: sorry... should I put <p> at the beginning of the line?

Comment: If the string "He is a boy" occurs anywhere in File_B you will have a match, otherwise no match. I guess I misunderstood what you wanted.

Comment: Hi d5e5, it is other way round. The big file contains all the lines and I don't think that I can create a string with 1G data. If I compare "a boy" with the big string "He is a boy. She is a girl....." I can only get a return value yes but I cannot locate the line and write it to the other file any more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how a hash table is going to help you search substrings. It's good for exact matches, though.

If your memory is not a constraint, maybe you could build a [suffix tree](http://marknelson.us/1996/08/01/suffix-trees/) from all the File A entries, which would give you very fast `O(N)` search times on File B entries.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I do think that hash table can help to do exact match. My boss ask me to put File_A and File_B in hashes, within the Foreach loop, use grep to check whether File_A contains File_B's data. In my mind, they will be using 2 Foreach loop, if File_A is 1000 lines, File_B is 50 lines, the program will loop 50000 times, I think that while loop and a 'found' condition can help to bring te loop count down.

Comment: If memory is a constraint, will the hash table help the loop or array is better? Someone told me that hash table put the things in the harddisk whilst array stores the data in the memory, is it true?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on linux you could write a shell script that sorts the files and then uses the 'uniq' program.  Sorting huge files first allows you to compare them without reading the entire files into memory.

Comment: Thx Dave, but I don't understand why I need to sort the file. The data is random in File_A. If the data is random, will the sorting help to improve the speed?

Comment: If you are dealing with **exact matches** (not what you are describing in your question, but whatever) then sorting will let you iterate through the file in a step-like fashion, going to the next line once a match is found.

Comment: Hi Alex, exactly! But as the data is a substring in a line, even I sort it, it will just sort the line and I do not think the content inside is still randomly distributed. The while loop with condition checking maybe the only way to bring down the loop-count.